# How do I control the size of images using CSS grid?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to set 9 images in a 3x3 grid, all of them with the same height and width. I'm able to set the grid but a couple of the images are smaller than the rest. Below I'm only showing how I formatted one of the photos. The HTML is the same for the other 8 photos.

```css
.items {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.item > img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="items">
     <div class="item">
        <div class="item-image">
           <img src="/dist/img_resources/vector1.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="item-text">
            <p class="item-description">Lorem, ipsum.</p>
            <p class="item-price">$X.XX</p>
         </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try, instead of wrapping the image, to put them directly as a grid cell. Then assign `.items > img { display: block; align-self: normal; }`

Comment: Also instead of using `div` consider the `figure` element, along with `figcaption`.